# How do you add multiple values into a array using for loops?

Tags: vba

(For future reference) Is it possible do something like this

```
For i = 0 to 11
array(i) = Label(i)
Next
```

Instead of brute forcing it by making 12 lines of something like
    array(0) = Label0, array(1) = Label1, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is

for instance

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ReDim myArray(0 To Me.Controls.count - 1) As MSForms.Label '<~~ declare this array with the maximum possible dimensions
    Dim lblCounter As Long
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control

    With Me '<~~ this refers to the UserForm object of which code pane you placed this code into
        For Each ctrl In .Controls '<~~ loop through UserForm controls
            If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then  '<~~ if you find a "Label"...
                Set myArray(lblCounter) = ctrl  '<~~ ... then store it in your array...
                lblCount = lblCounter + 1 '<~~ ... and update the label counter
            End If
        Next ctrl
    End With
    If lblCounter > 0 Then ReDim Preserve myArray(0 To lblCounter - 1) '<~~ if you actually found at least one label, then redim your array with proper dimensions
End Sub
```

of course you can place it in any event sub/eventhandler that has access to your Userform `Controls` collection